# What is the best battery topology for my inverter-charger application?

Tags: batteries, inverter, parallel, series

**Background**:

I have a Magnum Energy MSH3012RV 3kw inverter-charger that runs on 12VDC and I'd like to be able to discharge around 250 to 300 AH between recharges (from 120VAC input) without the batteries experiencing much more than 30% depth of discharge. Rates of discharge will be around 20-30A continuous with periodic short (~5 minute) bursts of up to 250-300A. Originally I had planned to purchase four 200AH/12VDC AGM batteries and put them in parallel, but upon further reading I've come to understand that batteries in parallel have a tendency to eat each other from charge oscillating back and forth between them due to slight differences in battery voltage. Now I'm looking at instead putting six 2V batteries in series.

**Questions**:

1) Is this inverter/battery topology sound? Is there a better way?

2) The particular batteries I am looking at are [these](https://documents.wholesalesolar.com/media/crown-2crv1200-agm-2-volt-battery-specs-2243747105.pdf). I need sealed/VRLA batteries for this application and my sense of things is that AGM batteries will serve me better than gel, but my understanding of battery technology is limited. Assuming my topology is good to go, are these batteries likely to be a good choice, or is there another type of battery or even a specific manufacturer I should  consider (or avoid)?

Comment: alibaba/ebay/amazon (etc..) batteries without data sheets are not recommended. Buy reputably sourced batteries from reputable manufacturers that provide bona fide data sheets.

Comment: Thanks. Is Rolls considered reputable? This battery has the voltage/capacity I need: https://www.rollsbattery.com/battery/s2-1275agm-re/

Comment: I've never heard of them but that's not a surprise because I'm not a battery expert.

Comment: It is very common in boats and RVs to have batteries in parallel.  If all batteries in a bank are same type and age, there should be no problems of "charge oscillating back and forth".

Comment: At least consider using some for of Lithium battery. You can safely have deeper depth of discharge so will not need as great an Ah capacity and peak discharge currents for a given Ah are usuallu higher.

Comment: Question is cross posted at [Sustainable Living SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/10009/99)